# Split String dynamic

Tags: java, split

I need a help to separate a String, Example:

`String trunk = "50 | 1 | 13"` / * DATABASE INFORMATION (Dynamic) * /

```
String[] dial_discagem = tronco.split("|");
```

I need to get the dial_disc information and call a "getDialDiscing" function by passing the trunk id. GetDialDiscing will return me a String where I have to mount it as follows.

```
dial = "SIP/trkfixo|SIP/TESTESIP|Khomp/b0l1";
```

I tried to do this:

```
String[] dial_discagem = tronco.split("|");
            String dial = "";

for(int i=0;i<dial_discagem.length;i++){

      String[] innerData = dial_discagem[i].split("|");
      String id = innerData[i];
      dial += getDialDiscagem(Integer.parseInt(id))+"|";
}
```

But this is giving the following error:

```
**Exception in thread "Thread-36" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at local.astman.db.CampanhaClienteChamadaDAO.getChamadasPendentes(CampanhaClienteChamadaDAO.java:303)**
```

Comment: Maybe you can re-consider the database design if *that* comes from the db. Also, check your for-body. It's pretty obvious where the problem lies.

Comment: Escape pipe character as it has special meaning in REGEX i.e. "|"

Comment: innerData and dial_discagem are two different things with different length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Declare and defined the array first e.g. outside the loop.

than you have to replace all the spaces than you can split by `|`.

**Sample Code**

```
String trunk = "50 | 1 | 13";
        String temp = trunk.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        String[] dial_discagem = temp.split("\\|");
        String dial = "";
        String[] innerData = new String[dial_discagem.length];
        for(int i=0;i<dial_discagem.length;i++){

          innerData[i] = dial_discagem[i];
          String id = innerData[i];
          dial += getDialDiscagem(Integer.parseInt(id))+"|";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you'll need a escape character such as :

```
final String dial = "SIP/trkfixo|SIP/TESTESIP|Khomp/b0l1";
final String[] discagem = dial.split("\\|");
for (int i = 0; i < discagem.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(discagem[i]);
}
```